# Adding overlapping routes when there is no overlapping route using buffer and union

Tags: python, polygon, buffer, shapely, linestring

I am trying to do something to do with routes, Let's say I have 3 routes rt1 and rt2 are overlapping routes that share some length but r3 does not overlap with either of them. How would I just add the overlapping route as I am confused and new to shapely and everything.

```
     wgs84 = CRS('EPSG:4326')
     utm = CRS('EPSG:32118')
     project = Transformer.from_crs(wgs84, utm, always_xy=True).transform

     rt1 = LineString([(-75.1949805258464,40.07651359825427),(-75.20269373099198, 40.08091315230035) ])

     rt2 = LineString([(-75.20130886000204, 40.080195561557595),(-75.2046746222474, 40.08211359104821 )])

     rt3 = LineString([(-75.20052000948208, 40.08295187369251), (-75.20349134643484, 40.08478264710011)])

    tot_length = {}
    buffered_routes = []
    routes = {'rt1': rt1,'rt2': rt2,'rt3': rt3}
    for k in routes:

      route = routes[k]
      projected_area = transform(project, route)
      buffer = projected_area.buffer(0.5)
      length = buffer.area
      comb.append(buffer)
    un = unary_union(comb).area
    print(un.area)#
    tot_length[x] = un
```

Initially what I am trying to do is find the overlapping route by buffering the linestring and adding them to a list and then using union to combine just the overlapping bit but maybe I am not getting the idea as I want to find the longest route out of rt. Can someone explain?

Comment: Sorry I was working with different ways and I forgot to change some of the parts